# Convert array key as object in laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I have an array as flight_names :

```
           [
               "Spice Jet",
               "Go Air",
               "Air India",
               "Vistara"
           ]
```

i want it to change to structure

```
           [
               {"flight_name":"Spice Jet"},
               {"flight_name":"Go Air"},
               {"flight_name":"Air India"},
               {"flight_name":"Vistara"}
           ]
```

Can anyone help me , how to change to this format in LARAVEL or PHP.

Comment: it seems you are confusing php and json. Explain better what you need.

Comment: i have resonse as above, i want to convert above array in below format using php laravel codes.

Comment: What did you try and where are you stuck? Add this info to the question please

Comment: you did not say more

Comment: actually one android people want the array in a format where each index is an object with flight_name and its value, i have an array which contains all the flight values, but i don't know how to convert array values to object same as above structure

Answer (score 1):

You can use json_encode if its json output,

```
$arr    = ["Spice Jet", "Go Air", "Air India", "Vistara"];
$result = json_encode(array_map(function ($item) {
    return (array_combine(['flight_name'], [$item]));
}, $arr), JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
print_r($result);die;
```

**reference**: [array-combine](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-combine.php), [array-map](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php) & [json-encode](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php).

> **JSON_PRETTY_PRINT**
>   Use whitespace in returned data to format it. Available as of PHP 5.4.0.

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/WdRYq)

Simple foreach loop,

```
$arr = ["Spice Jet", "Go Air", "Air India", "Vistara"];
foreach($arr as &$v){
    $v = (array_fill_keys([$v], "flight_name"));
}
print_r(json_encode($arr));die;
```

**Reference**: [array-fill-keys](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill-keys.php)

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/eXkGH).

A simplified version of array_map,

```
$result =array_map(function($item){
    return ['flight_name' => $item];
}, $arr);
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/GLdaC).

A Simplified foreach,

```
foreach($arr as &$v){
    $v = ['flight_name' => $v];
}
print_r(json_encode($arr));die;
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/2UdUo).

To reverse your output,

```
foreach($arr as &$v){
    $v = array_flip(json_decode($v, true));
}
```

**Output**

```
[
    {
        "flight_name": "Spice Jet"
    },
    {
        "flight_name": "Go Air"
    },
    {
        "flight_name": "Air India"
    },
    {
        "flight_name": "Vistara"
    }
]
```

Comment: sir I have a simple array as above and want the array to convert as the second structure.

I have edited my question

Comment: I have made changes in my answer. Please have a look. Now my output exactly matching with yours :)

Comment: sir, i am getting exactly what i want but, key and values are swapped, can you help to reorder them?
                 [
                    {
                        "Spice Jet": "flight_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "Go Air": "flight_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "Air India": "flight_name"
                    },
                    {
                        "Vistara": "flight_name"
                    }
                ]

Comment: what you did? use my snippet. The last one of snippets will be better.

Comment: Please check my `To reverse your output` portion of answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
 $airlineArray=["Spice Jet", "Go Air", "Air India", "Vistara"];
    $finalArray=[];
    foreach($airlineArray as $key=>$value)
     {
       $arrayValue = ['flight_name' => $value];
          $finalArray[]=$arrayValue;
      }
     return $finalArray;
```